# Best model to predict failure using time series from sensors

Tags: python, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, prediction

I'm working with a company on a project to develop ML models for predictive maintenance. The data we have is a collection of log files. In each log file we have time series from sensors (Temperature, Pressure, MototSpeed,...) and a variable in which we record the faults occurred. The aim here is to build a model that will use the log files as its input (the time series) and to predict whether there will be a failure or not. For this I have some questions:
1) What is the best model capable of doing this?
2) What is the solution to deal with imbalanced data? In fact, for some kind of failures we don't have enough data. 
I tried to construct an RNN classifier using LSTM after transforming the time series to sub time series of a fixed length. The targets were 1 if there was a fault and 0 if not. The number of ones compared to the number of zeros is negligible. As a result, the model always predicted 0. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mohamed, for this problem you could actually start with traditional ML models (random forest, lightGBM, or anything of this nature). I recommend you focus on your features. For example you mentioned Pressure, MototSpeed. Look at some window of time going back. Calculate moving averages, min/max values in that same window, st.dev. To tackle this problem you will need to have a set of healthy features. Take a look at featuretools package. You can either use it or get some ideas what features can be created using time series data. Back to your questions.

1) What is the best model capable of doing this? Traditional ML methods as mentioned above. You could also use deep learning models, but I would first start with easy models. Also if you do not have a lot of data I probably would not touch RNN models.

2) What is the solution to deal with imbalanced data? You may want to oversample or undersample your data. For oversampling look at the SMOTE package.

Good luck